# Inequality for an alternating sum of binomial coefficients times a fraction

Tags: binomial-coefficients, fractions

I need to show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^x(-1)^n  {x\choose n}\left(\frac{1}{n+l-1}-\frac{1}{n+l}\right) >0,$$

for any $l>0$. I tried to prove this, but I didn't get anywhere.

Apparently the above sum is equal to $\frac{(l-2)!(x+1)!}{(x+l)!}$. However I have no idea how to prove this either. Any tips on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{1}{a}=\int_{0}^{1} z^{a-1}\,dz $, we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=0}^{x}\binom{x}{n}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{n+l-1}-\frac{1}{n+l}\right) &=& \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\binom{x}{n}(-1)^n\left(z^{n+l-2}-z^{n+l-1}\right) \,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}(1-z)^x\left(z^{l-2}-z^{l-1}\right)\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}(1-z)^{x+1} z^{l-2}\,dz.\end{eqnarray*} $$

The last integral is clearly positive and can be computed through [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), or simply by integration by parts.

Comment: @Leanne: you're welcome.